# Getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when posting http request to local host in angular-js framework

Tags: angularjs, http-post

```
<$http.post('http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/',{text:'Hello'},{params:{id:'5'}});>
```

I m new to angularJS and http request's , when I'm posting this request and checking the same in Chrome dev tool ,err_empty_request error is coming.

Can any one guide what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi @aditya seems like the response you post is not correct i'm not sure what it is, but it's not a legit request, can you please give more details or ad jsfiddle so i can help you?

Comment: you have to post your code, front-end and back-end

Comment: @LiadLivnat [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEgjTn2cn9yTUahnBoKS?p=preview).This is the plunker ,here when i'm using get and in URL giving todos.json it is working .In post method in url giving path for my local host . Is something wrong here ? Kindly help

Comment: @Aditya thanks, for some reason i can't load the plunker, can you send jsfiddle instead?

Comment: ok it's working now, but i'm not sure what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Liad i will try it , actually [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdCsgZSyyJapdeJprEd6?p=preview) this is the actual code .

Comment: @LiadLivnat [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdCsgZSyyJapdeJprEd6?p=preview) ,ne pointers on this plunker.Unable to access php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code instead:

```
var controller_data = {"text":"hello","id":"5"};
$http({url: 'http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application1/' , method: "POST",withCredentials: true,data:controller_data});
```